# Optimistic concurrency in Rackspace OpenStack Cloud File

Tags: azure, cloud, openstack, rackspace, cloudfiles

How do you practise optimistic concurrency when updating a **Cloud File** on **Rackspace**.

In **Azure blob storage** I would:

- GET the blob
- Make a note of its etag
- Modify the blob
- Upload the modified blob with etag in an If-None-Match header.

This means if someone else has uploaded the modified blob between my GET and upload, my upload would fail as the etag wouldn't match (I then re-GET then modify and upload again).

*ANYWAY*, I can't find a facility to do that with Cloud Files. I can get an etag of a blob I plan to modify but I cannot send it back with the If-None-Match header as I would expect. You can send an etag header but this expects an MD5 checksum of the data I'm sending, not what they already have.

As far as I can see there is no Last Modified request header to send either.

**What to do here to ensure modifications aren't lost during concurrent work to Cloud Files?**